# Want to change video src with input field

Tags: javascript, html, video, input, src

Beginner here using JavaScript for the first time. I want to have a video playing on my site, but when I input a certain word in the input field and submit it, I want it to change the `src` attribute of the video.

I'd have five or six different words and each of those would have a different video "assigned" to them.

Here's what I tried so far:

```js
const myInputField = document.getElementById('field');
const myButton = document.getElementById('button');
const myVideo = document.getElementById('video');

myButton.addEventListener("click", changeSrc);

var a = myInputField.value;

function changeSrc(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  if (a === "BRUH") {
    myVideo.src = "vid2.mp4";
  } else {;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div>
    <form>
      <input type="text" id="field" oninput="let p=this.selectionStart;this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();this.setSelectionRange(p, p);">
      <button type="submit" id="button">CONFIRM</button>
    </form>
  </div>
  <div>
    <video src="vid1.mp4" id="video" width="640" height="480" loop="true" autoplay="autoplay" muted></video>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const myInputField = document.getElementById('field');
const myButton = document.getElementById('button');
const myVideo = document.getElementById('video');
    
myButton.addEventListener("click", changeSrc);

var a = myInputField.value;

function changeSrc(event) {
    event.preventDefault ();

switch(myInputField.value){
       case "WORD1":
    myVideo.src = "vid1.mp4";
    break;
     case "WORD2":
    myVideo.src = "vid2.mp4";
    break;
     case "WORD3":
    myVideo.src = "vid3.mp4";
    break;
     case "WORD4":
    myVideo.src = "vid4.mp4";
    break;
     case "WORD5":
    myVideo.src = "vid5.mp4";
    break;
       
       }
       
    }
```